# High on %wa from top command, is there any way to constrain it?

Tags: linux, centos, io, cgroups

Here's my last top info before it stucks:

```
top - 18:26:10 up 238 days,  5:43,  3 users,  load average: 1782.01, 1824.47, 1680.36
Tasks: 1938 total,   1 running, 1937 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  2.4%us,  3.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id, 94.5%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  65923016k total, 65698400k used,   224616k free,    13828k buffers
Swap: 33030136k total, 17799704k used, 15230432k free,   157316k cached
```

As you can see, since I've launched about 2000 processes executing `hadoop get` command, **%wa** is very high. I limit memory and cpu in `cgroups`, will it be helpful if I limit disk IO, too? If so, could anyone give me some idea on how to do that in `cgroups`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system is swapping heavily (17G swap used) which will make any I/O from regular processes to the respective drive extremely slow - which translates into high `%wa`.

Not 100% sure but even swapping itself may contribute directly to the `%wa` figure as well (typically via the `kswapd` process, also likely the top CPU hugger in your situation).

First you want to limit the number of processes so that no (or very little) swap is used and then re-check the %wa and evaluate if you actually need to constrain the I/O for those processes.